# Huge memory usage with circular pipeline

Tags: memory, pipeline, raku

Update 2:
As @Valle Lukas pointed out, Looks like this is due to a leak being addressed.

Update 1:

Ok I got around to trying this again and have a much simpler bit of code that demonstrates the issue I'm having:

```
my $channel=Channel.new;    #create a new channel
$channel.send(0);           #kickstart the circular pipeline
react {
    whenever $channel {
        say $_;
        $channel.send($_ + 1); #send back to same pipeline
        #sit back and watch the memory usage grow
    }
}
```

Basically I create a single stage pipeline via a `Channel`, send a single message to it, then setup `react`/`whenever` blocks to process the message (add 1) and send it back to the same channel again. The pipeline once started never stops.

The growth in memory usage ( I get to about 600MB and climbing in about 10 seconds), isn't due to message buffering, there is only ever one message in the cue.

Is this simply a bug or how can I address the memory usage of a channel?

Comment: Have you tried looking at a profile of your code (`perl6 --profile`) and see if that gives any indication as to why the memory usage?

Comment: I have, but I don't know what to make of it really. The top three allocations are  'BOOTCode', 'Block' and then 'Scalar'.  'BOOTCode' is about 3 times larger than the next largest.

Comment: In a slightly different version where I used `@array >>+>> 1` to monitor the changes in the data through the pipeline, I had a bunch of  Num allocations showing in the profiler. That makes sense I guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems to be addressed by Jonathan Worthington commit

[d5044de](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/commit/d5044de2f7c2101ae6a24da8263ce8e1bd41dc81)

and

[25b486d](https://github.com/MoarVM/MoarVM/commit/25b486dee8a0f66a944d4a25279de8e7c315807f)